# Can I apply for an Irish visit visa and a UK visit visa at the same time?

Tags: uk, international-travel, standard-visitor-visas, ireland

Me and my family are going to Dublin and Belfast for 10 days, they are US citizens and I am a green card holder and a Filipino citizen living in the US. I have read on the website for Ireland and UK that I have to apply 3 months before traveling. Both visa take 8 weeks to get and it is said that I have to apply for Irish visa first before UK visa.

Now if I had to do that I won't have enough time to get my UK visa before we leave.

Have you guys experienced applying to both Irish and UK visit visa?

Comment: Where have you read that UK visas take 8 weeks? Typical published timescales are 10-15 working days, although of course there’s no guarantee

Comment: Yes, you are right it takes 2 weeks or more for uk visa. But still I will only have 1 month left after I get my Irish visa to process my  uk visa.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can.

> Now if I had to do that I won't have enough time to get my UK visa before we leave.

They will not help an applicant with a tight schedule just because an applicant failed to apply in time unless there is an emergency.

You will definitely need both visas before you travel there (legally), so your best bet is to use **Priority processing** options and pay extra fee to get the decisions quicker. Although UK visas do not require 8 weeks, specially not from the US. You can check for your location [here](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y).

You also have an option of keeping your passport while applying for the British visa (you have to pay extra) . That way you can apply for both visas at the same time and send your passport for Irish visa and get the UK visa stamped after/if they call you for it.

Comment: So I can apply uk visa first before the irish visa? even the main destination is Ireland? Sorry kinda stupid question. It said here http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Will%20an%20Irish%20visa%20allow%20me%20to%20travel%20to%20Northern%20Ireland   that if northern ireland is main destination I have to apply uk visa first. Sorry english isnt my 1st language Im a little bad in comprehending. Thanks.

Comment: @Eka Mancon Northern Ireland is part of the U.K...